# C, malloc, free, and automated checking

Tags: c, malloc

I have a very long convoluted piece of undocumented nightmare code that I have to use, full of mallocs and frees. I have already found a couple that are not matched correctly. Is there any automated source code examination tool that would help me analyse it?

Comment: Which platform are you interested in?

Comment: I'm using ST-LINK on a Discovery board based around the STM32F303x with IAR EWARM

Comment: Any good [static code analyzer](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#C.2FC.2B.2B) should be a good start.

Comment: IF your code can be made to compile & run on Linux, consider [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 2):

There is a GNU tool for this: It is called GDB, stands for the Gnu DeBugger.  You can use it to load a piece of code compiled with the appropriate debug symbols.  Then you can use it to put in a temporary break and step through it manually to see exactly what is going on, and you can examine individual functions/subroutines.

Answer (score 1):

For C language, following open-source STATIC CODE ANALYSER tool should be good start.

Cppcheck – Open-source tool that checks for several types of errors, including use of STL.
cpplint – An open-source tool that checks for compliance with Google's style guide for C++ coding.
Clang – An open-source compiler that includes a static analyzer.